# Higher Order Functions with Express Routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I was looking at a blog https://www.acuriousanimal.com/2018/02/15/express-async-middleware.html on how to handle do await/async in Typescript express routes.

I liked the idea of using the Higher Order Functions to avoid code redundancy, but

1. am not sure how to do it in TypeScript
2. Is there any other better way TypeScript recommends for this kind of scenario

Sample Code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/kameshsampath/e550d5bf19feb9b59d0ec1871e59b53a

Comment: Why are you "not sure how to do it in Typescript" ? It is the same as javascript. Are you having difficulties with assigning types? Show some code that is giving you difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to remove the `catch` from the following code into a higher order function:

```
app.get("/api/frames", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  //TODO move this to higher order function
  try {
    const qCollection = await loadCollection("frames", db);
    const docs = qCollection.find();
    if (docs) {
      return res
        .contentType("json")
        .status(200)
        .send(docs);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  }
    app.get("/api/frames", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  //TODO move this to higher order function
  try {
    const qCollection = await loadCollection("frames", db);
    const docs = qCollection.find();
    if (docs) {
      return res
        .contentType("json")
        .status(200)
        .send(docs);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  }
});
```

This does that:

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) =>
  Promise
    .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
    .catch((err)=>res.status(404).send(err);)

app.get("/api/frames", asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
    const qCollection = await loadCollection("frames", db);
    const docs = qCollection.find();
    if (docs) {
      return res
        .contentType("json")
        .status(200)
        .send(docs);
    }
 }));
```